# Should we call PowerManger's reboot method in a separate thread?

Tags: java, android, powermanager, android-powermanager

I need to programmatically reboot an android device, and the PowerManager's `reboot` functionality comes in handy.

**My question is:**
Should `reboot` be called in a separate thread or is it okay to call it in the same thread?

Comment: You don't state whether or not you consulted the official documentation on that functionality; please either consult that or report back that you did so and why that did not help you.

Comment: The official documentation doesn't state anything about my question.
Hence I made a stackOverflow account to ask this question.

Comment: That's fair. My point is that SO's guidelines are that your question should reflect the research you've already done on your side prior to asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am not an Android developer, here's what I found.

tl;dr : I haven't seen examples of calling reboot in it's own thread; have you?

[Here's the official reboot docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#reboot(java.lang.String))
[image]

[Here's a SO answer on using reboot, no mention of calling it in a separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17190620/483257)

[Here's a 'crowd-sourced cookbook' article about using reboot; nomention of calling it in a separate thread](https://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=2077)

Guessing the API handles it gracefully automatically for you.

Comment: Yes I have seen code which has the `reboot` called in its own thread. (I can't post the link because the code isn't open-source). 
Since there is no logical reason I see which to prefer, I guess we could do it either way.

Comment: Oh interesting. I agree. Personally, I'd go with simpler as long as it results in a reboot. At least later if you start getting strange behavior you'll know a possible tweak to address it.